# x-axis, y-axis, first axis, second axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis

I am currently trying to establish conventions to treat my 4D dataset, but matlab confuses me with its indexing names :

When I load for example an image with :

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
```

I get a 384 × 512 × 3 matrix, which means 384 pixels along the first dimension, 512 pixels along the second dimension, and 3 channels along the third dimension. But when I plot the image with imshow and label the right bottom point :

```
figure; imshow(RGB);
```

[image: peppers]

It seems that Matlab calls the first dimension axis 'Y' and the second dimension axis 'X'.

I found in the documentation how to change the axis direction with 'XDir' and 'YDir' properties `set(gca, 'YDir', 'normal')`, but I did not find how to change their names.

I would like to fit to the 'RAST' standard (right-anterior-superior-time) and to name the 1rst, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th dimensions respectively x,y,z,t without having to transpose / flip my images everytime I want to display them.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Matlab's dimension order is rows then columns, so you have 384 rows, which is a height of 384, ergo a size in the y direction of 384. Note also that `imshow` that the upper left is the origin, which is not normal for other MATLAB plots. If you use [`shiftdim`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) or similar to swap dimensions, you could quickly confuse things more.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I finally use [`permute`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) only for plotting.